# typescript unable to sort fetched data from api "(TypeError): Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fetch-api

This is my first time writing typescript and I want to fetch external data from an API. The problem is that this data comes unsorted so I have to sort it by date.

With my custom hook below I get the data and try to sort it but I get the error:

> "(TypeError): Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined"

I would appreciate your help .

```
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
  
//SORTING FUNCTION BY DATE STRING 
const  dateToNum = (d:string):number => {
  // Convert date "2016-06-26" to 20160626 and compare 
  d.split("-"); 
  return Number(d[0]+d[1]+d[2]);

}

export default function useFetch(date1:string, date2:string) {
  
  const [loading,setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [error,setError] = useState<string>("");
  const [data,setData] = useState<[]>([]);
   
  const fetchData = async () =>{
    const url = `https://data.gov.gr/api/v1/query/mdg_emvolio?date_from=${date1}&date_to=${date2}`;
    
    try{
      setLoading(true);
      setData([]);
      fetch(url,{
          method:'GET',
          headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "Authorization": `Token ${process.env.REACT_APP_EMVOLIO_API_KEY}`
          },
        }
      ).then((res)=>{
        res.json()
      }).then((dt:any)=>{
       //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR HITS AS IT DOES NOT RECOGNISE THE JSON ARRAY 
       dt.sort((a:any,b:any)=>  dateToNum(a.referencedate.slice(0,10)) -  dateToNum(b.referencedate.slice(0,10)))
        setData(dt);
      })
     
    }catch(error){
      setError(error);
    }

    setLoading(false);

  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData();
  },[date1,date2])


  return {loading,data,error};
}
```

I also tried `async-await`:

```
 try{
      setLoading(true);
      setData([]);
      let response = await fetch(url,{
          method:'GET',
          headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "Authorization": `Token ${process.env.REACT_APP_EMVOLIO_API_KEY}`
          },
        }
      );
     let res = await response.json();
     res = res.sort((a:any,b:any)=>  dateToNum(a.referencedate.slice(0,10)) -  
       dateToNum(b.referencedate.slice(0,10)));
     
     setData(res);
     
    }catch(error){
      setError(error);
    }
```

Async await set the data on the array but did not sort it.

I would appreciate your help here.

Comment: let res = await response.json();  why?

Comment: `.then((res)=>{ res.json() })` doesn't return anything from the fulfillment callback, so the result is `undefined`. See the linked question's answers, you need a `return` there or you need to use the concise form of the arrow function. Side note: Your code is also falling prey to the `fetch` API footgun I describe [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html), you need to check for HTTP success.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi - Why not? The `json` method on the `Response` object returns a promise.

Comment: *"Async await set the data on the array but did not sort it ."* It clearly does call `sort` on it, but apparently the sort callback doesn't do what you expect it to do. The best way to figure out why that is is to step through it with the debugger built into your browser and/or IDE.

Comment: Finally: Beware that with any asynchronous operation that results in your calling a state setter, you need to be sure that your component hasn't been unmounted in the meantime.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I wrote return on my response.json() but still no sorting . I will try using the debugger but I would appreciate a different approach as well

Comment: @VASILEIOSSKENTOS - Well, again, your `await` version should work (by which I mean, it'll call `sort`) other than not checking the HTTP result. There are some other things I'd change as well that [I've listed here](https://pastebin.com/XktExkc1), but fundamentally if your `await` version above *"set the data on the array but did not sort it"*, you need to look at your `sort` callback because it's clearly being called.